# ARIMA model with splitted data

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, box-jenkins

> **Question**: When analyzing a time series of size $N$ assume that you fit models for data in the intervals $[1,N/2]$, $[N/2+1,N]$,
>   $[1,(2/3)N]$ and $[(2/3)N+1,N]$. Discuss what this approach is for.

In this case, all intervals are disjoint and the union of those represents the complete data set.

What I read here [Forecasting with Univariate Box - Jenkins Models: Concepts and Cases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471090239)  is that the model may well fit the data as a whole, but the distant past or recent past are poorly adjusted and therefore the predictions can be bad.

But why four models?